# can you change azureml rest endpoint from public to private

Tags: azure, security, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Is it possible to have private endpoints in azure ml? I want to change the endpoint from public to private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to make your endpoint private by using a VPN for your workspace

"Azure Private Link enables you to connect to your workspace using a private endpoint. The private endpoint is a set of private IP addresses within your virtual network"

docs has more detail about this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-private-link?tabs=cli

If it is not possible to use a vpn, another work around could be to deploy your models using azure function apps.

function apps have different levels of authentication and therefore is much more secure then a public endpoint that anyone can access.

function app security- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4

beginners guide to function app- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration